# The solid torus $X$ is the solid of revolution in $\mathbb R^3$ gotten by revolving the circle around the z axis

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The solid torus $X$ is the solid of revolution in $\mathbb R^3$  gotten by revolving the circle around the $z$-axis, in other words a donut. Its boundary $T$ is the torus.

Describe the homomorphism $i_* : \pi_1(T) \to \pi_1(X)$ between the fundamental groups induced by the inclusion map.

I really have no idea how to approach this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the structure of $\pi_1(T)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, it's Z*Z

Comment: Right, so it has two generators. Can you describe loops corresponding to these generators?

Comment: (I would say $X$ is gotten by revolving a disk, not a circle.) Given a function $f\colon A\to B$, do you know the definition of $f^*\colon \pi(A)\to \pi(B)$? If so, what happens when you apply that definition to the map $i$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That is the part i'm not sure about. I think its from Z*Z to Z, but I don't know how it works.

Comment: $\pi_1(T) = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly know there exists a homeomorphism $h: S^1 \times S^1 \to T$. See for example [Finding the description of a homeomorphism from $S^1 \times S^1$ onto the surface of doughnut.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3161531).

This homeomorphism extends to a homeomorphism $H: S^1 \times D^2 \to X$. Under this homeomorphism the inclusion $i : T \to X$ corresponds to the inclusion $J = id \times j : S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \times D^2$, where $j : S^1  \hookrightarrow D^2$.

For any two pointed spaces $(X_k,x_{0k})$ let $p_k : (X_1 \times X_2, (x_{01},x_{02})) \to(X_k,x_{0k})$ be the projection maps onto the $k$-th factor. It is well-known that the homomorphism
$$P : \pi_1(X_1 \times X_2) \to \pi_1(X_1) \times \pi_1(X_2), P(c) = ((p_1)_*(c),(p_2)_*(c)$$
is an isomorphism of groups.

This yields the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\pi_1(S^1 \times S^1) @>{P}>>\pi_1(S^1) \times \pi_1(S^1) @= \mathbb Z  \times \mathbb Z  @= \mathbb Z  \times \mathbb Z \\
@V{J_*}VV @V{id _*\times j_*}VV @VV{id \times 0}V @VV{p}V\\
\pi_1(S^1 \times D^2) @>{P}>> \pi_1(S^1) \times \pi(D^2) @= \mathbb Z  \times 0 @= \mathbb Z \end{CD}
where $p(a,b) = a$. This should answer your question.